# PHP strftime not displaying correct output

Tags: php, strftime

I'm probably doing something really silly here, but this isn't giving the expected output:

```
php > $time = "2011-05-05 20:15:29"; // Timestamp from MySQL database, in UTC.
php > date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
php > $ts = strtotime($time . " UTC");
php > strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
php > echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
2011-05-05 17:51:59
```

Year, month and day are correct, but everything (including seconds?) is off. Why?

Comment: What is the output you are getting from line 3?

Comment: arent you supposed to pass $ts to the strftime function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this because you aren't passing arguement 2 to `strftime`?

```
echo strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 1304626529 ); // 2011-05-05 20:15:29 UTC
```

Comment: Like I said, I was probably doing something silly. Head was firmly planted into wall here.

Comment: @Thanatos, happens to all of us :)